# Compiling Visual Studio project as a pre-commit git hook

Tags: git, visual-studio, pre-commit-hook

Is there a way to create a git pre-commit hook that will try to compile the Visual Studio project I'm committing in several configurations and then allowing for the commit only if all compilations succeed?

I get the general idea of how to write a pre-commit hook, but that's all bash, so I'm not sure if I can make it to run what I'm guessing is a `MSBuild.exe` with the configuration of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended being much simpler than I anticipated. I my case I wanted to run both debug and release configurations on x64 platform.

```
#!/bin/bash

MSBuild="path\to\MSBuild.exe"

if ! exec "$MSBuild" VulkanRT.sln -t:build -p:Configuration=Debug -p:Platform=x64 | grep -q "Build succeeded."
then
    echo "Debug build failed!"
    exit 1
elif ! exec "$MSBuild" VulkanRT.sln -t:build -p:Configuration=Debug -p:Platform=x64 | grep -q "Build succeeded."
then
    echo "Release build failed!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Release and debug build succeeded!"
exit 0
```

Note that this is only viable for smaller projects where build times are low, unless you're fine waiting on the long build times.